# Using select query to retrieve distinct values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a select statement to get unique values in a column through a macro. But executing the select statement throws an error. What's worse, the error dialog shows no error message:

[image: Error Dialog]

The code I'm using is:

```
Sub DataFilter()
Dim adoConnection       As Object
Dim rcdSource           As Object
Dim strSource           As String, srcName As String
Dim lngLoop             As Long
MsgBox "Hailo"
Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rcdSource = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

SourceWbk = ActiveWorkbook.Name
strSource = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
MsgBox "strSource is " & strSource

adoConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strSource & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES"";"
rcdSource.Open "SELECT DISTINCT [Movie Name] FROM [MyExcel_File$] "

End Sub
```

Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Amber, check the examples here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257819, you are missing connectionstring in your connection.open code

Comment: `[MyExcel_File$]` is the *sheet* name?

Comment: @Alex K. No, it's the file name

Comment: It should be the sheet name IIRC